# Java serialization, is it automatic at all?

Tags: java, serialization

I have to serialize a specific class objects with these attributes:

```
int fetchCount
String requestMethod
long responeTime
int initialAge

byte[] responseEntity
HttpResponse response
    BasicHeader[] headers
        BasicHeader header
            String name
            String value
    Locale locale
        String language
        String country
        String variant
    BasicHttpParams params  IS SERIALIZABLE

    BasicStatusLine statusLine
        ProtocolVersion protocolVersion IS SERIALIZABLE
        int statusCode
        String reasonPhrase
```

All the final objects of each subclass are serializable, then the question is: the serialization/deserialization of all this complex structure is automatic?

Comment: `Maps` and `Arrays` are [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) so You should not face any problems. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: No problems, is the first time I face with serialization and I have doubts on result. What about the possible representation I proposed for non-serializable objects? I think it should be ok...

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implements  [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) so you will not face any problems unless `key` and `value` inside HashMap also implements [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Primitives, Arrays, String are Serializable so in second case I see no problem